# what does get_the_terms() wordpress function mean?

Tags: wordpress

I need your help.

I have read in WordPress codes that get_the_terms() mthod retrieve the **terms of the taxonomy** that are attached to the post, but really I do not understand what taxonomy mean in WordPress and I can't understand how this method work.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_the_terms()` is to be used within *the WordPress loop*. The function takes 2 parameters: `$id` and `$taxonomy`. So for a very simplified example, inside your `single.php` template you could do this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

Visiting `example.com/post-name-here` in your browser you would see displayed on the page all of the terms (or *tags* in the case of this example) that have been assigned to the post "post-name-here".

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms
- http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 1):

The term [`Taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) refers to a group of elements. Taxonomy is a collective under which custom taxonomies, category, post tag,post format and link category falls.

Wordpress categorise these into two groups, build-in and custom taxonomies. Category, post tag, post format and category link are build-in taxonomies, and then taxonomies created by `register_taxonomy` are custom taxonomies

Stricktly speaking, all tags and all categories and all terms created in a custom taxonomy which you create in the back end is defined as `terms`.

For example, `uncategorized` is a term of the taxonomy `category`. If create a tag called `test`, then test is a term of the taxonomy `post-tag`